# Error on executing HTTP request in android

Tags: android, httprequest

I know it may seems to dumb question and there are lots of such questions but I have problems but I can't figure it out what does errors in log means. I know these http methods are deprecated and I should replace them, but I want to get response now. This is my code:

```
    try
    {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
        responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        responsePhrase = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        if(responseEntity != null)
        {
            InputStream is = responseEntity.getContent();
            responseString = convertStreamToString(is);
            try
            {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception ignored) { }
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        onError(e);
    }
```

The codes goes to catch block when it tries to run `httpClient.execute` and the `e` object is null. This is log:

```
10-17 18:07:19.404  21766-21766/? E/Mms/ipmsg/compose﹕ saveIpMessageDraft(): mIpMessageDraft is null!
java.lang.Exception
        at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.saveIpMessageDraft(ComposeMessageActivity.java:13622)
        at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.onSaveInstanceState(ComposeMessageActivity.java:3870)
        at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1147)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1291)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3336)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3402)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I couldn't figure it out what errors are. I searched through web I couldn't find anything about `saveIpMessageDraft` or `mIpMessageDraft`. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: This is not the stacktrace from your app but the platform MMS app.

Comment: What is platform MMS?

Comment: Multimedia Messaging. But it doesn't really matter: it's just not your stacktrace.

Comment: @Taher can you run it in debug mode and make sure that it gets to the `onError(e);` part of the code, put a break point there, as it looks like it's throwing an exception from another place not your applciation. Same as #laalto said

Comment: OK, How can i see stacktrace? I types --full-stacktrace in File->settings->compiler.

Comment: @infinity yes it gets to the onError(e); it gets there when it tries to run httpClient.execute

Comment: can you check the `e.getMessage()` once in the catch block, I suspect this is no the full stack trace.