# How to enable stacktrace in android studio? Where is its window?

Tags: android, android-studio, stack-trace

I develop an app which has problem in HTTP execute method. Someone suggested me to check stacktrace. But I don't know how!

So how can I enable it? where is exactly its window?

I put `--full-stacktrace` in `File > Settings > compiler > command-line options` . So I just see Threads and Frames in Debugger window.

(I know about log cat and I use it, I need to use stack trace)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for Logcat. The keybind to bring it up is Alt+6. You can also bring it up by clicking on it at the bottom of android studio:

[image: Logcat]

Perhaps you are catching the exception but ignoring the result, you can log your stacktrace like this:

```
public void doSomething() {
    try {
        //do something that might throw an exception
    } catch (Exception e) { //be as specific as possible when catching an exception
        Log.e("ExceptionTag", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: NO, I know what is log cat. I asked a question before and i put my logs, but they said, put your stack trace too.

Comment: Stacktraces go to LogCat by default, unless you're using a custom logging implementation. Perhaps you are catching an exception but not printing it's stacktrace?

Comment: In the try catch block, I use printStackTrace(); getMessage(); to put my logs in log cat.

Comment: Then the stack trace should get printed to the logcat. Are you filtering your logcat (check the filter box) and have you selected the correct device (it might be messed up if you have a phone as well as an emulator connected)?

Comment: No. I use No Filter option. Could you please check my previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33188052/2965799

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92698/discussion-between-nbokmans-and-taher).